# What is exactly copied during class slicing?

Tags: c++, class

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        A():m(1){};
        int m;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        B (): A(),m(2),n(3){};
        void print(){cout<<'?';};
        int m,n;
};

int main (int, char *[]) {
    B b;
    A a1 = b;
    cout<<a1.m<<endl;       // This prints out 1 instead of 2.

    
return 0;
};
```

Brief code explanation: I declared and defined two class `A` and `B`, where `B` inherits from `A`. Class `A` and `B` both contains member variable `m`.

When I say `A a1 = b;`, I understand that member variable `n` of instance `b` won't get copied to `a1`, because of class slicing. My question is why member variable `m` is not copied as well?

(My thought is like: Both instance `a1` and `b` contain member variable `m`, so when initializing `a1` with `b`, the copy constructor of `a1` will be called, and member variable within class `A` will get copied from `b`.)   Is that correct?

More generally, during class slicing, what exactly is copied to the recipient?

Comment: See the dupe, this is called object slicing. If you have a more specific question, edit it into the question.

Comment: It's not a good idea to hide base members by using the same name in derived classes. The `B b` object contains *two* distinct `int m;` members: `b.m` and `b.A::m`. Slicing only copies the latter over to `a1`.

Comment: The confusion comes because you have _two_ member variables with the same name, `A::m` and `B::m`. In the `A a1 = b;` declaration, the `A` base class of `b` is copied, which copies over the `A::m` value (which was initialized to 1 in `A::A`).

Comment: What exactly happens is that the target base class part is copied via its copy constructor.